# Gradle copy task, relative path

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, relative-path, gradle-task

I have two gradle modules(**A** and **B**). Module **B** depends on module **A**.

Module **A** contains `Copy` task from relative path:

```
task copyStrings(type: Copy){
    from '../path/'
    into 'folder'
}

tasks.preBuild.dependsOn('copyStrings')
```

When I execute `./gradlew assemble` from module **A** it works perfectly.

But when I am assembling module **B**, gradle can't found such directory, because relative path is made from module **B** directory.

Is there any way to set working directory for `Copy` task?

Comment: Could you please try `from project.file('../path/')`?

Comment: Also, there's no need for `<<`, `task copyStrings(type: Copy) {
    from '../path/'
    into 'folder'
}` is all you need. [Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/41182383) is a small demo.

Comment: It is not only not needed, but plainly wrong and probably just an error in the question, because with the `<<` the task will never be executed as it has no inputs defined during configuration phase but only during execution phase which is plainly wrong and will not work in this case.

Comment: Yes, @Vampire, you're 100% right!

Comment: @Opal I have edited the question. This is definitely not a reason of not resolving path

Comment: I don't know the whole setup but it definitely wasn't right. Please let me know if my answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try:

```
from project.file('../path/')
```

Also, there's no need for `<<`:

```
task copyStrings(type: Copy) { 
   from '../path/' into 'folder' 
}
```

is all you need. [Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/41182383) you can find a little demo.